# Need help on bask awk to update Yaml file by finding the pattern in the file

Tags: awk, yaml, line

CONTEXT: I am very new to UNIX scripting and `bash`.

I have a `.bash` script that takes a `.yaml` and an array of VMs passed as arguments.

(e.g.)

```sh
myscript.sh my.yaml neo1 neo2 neo3 alice1 alice2 alice3
```

How to find the monitor_vm key pattern and file the last lime of the that monitor section and add at the last lines of that section?

Have got one sample function which identifies some pattern to give line number of that inserting line ....but it requires some changes. Please advise
example

```sh
getline() {
  awk '
    BEGIN { monitor_vms="'${}'"; ln=1; fnd=0; }
      (fnd==1 && $0 ~ /^  [a-z]/) { exit }
      ($0~/^monitor_vms:/) { fnd = 1 }
      ($0 ~ /./ && $0 !~ /^#/) { ln = NR }
    END { print ln }' ${1}
}


for name in $VM_LIST; do
  line=`getline my.yaml monitor_vms`
  sed -i -e ${line}"a\- name: \"${vmname}\"\n my.yaml
done
```

The file `my.yaml` looks like the following:

```yaml
---
- someotherkey: hello
  value: some_value
- someotherkey1: hello1
  value1: some_value1
- monitor_vms:
  - name:  sujana
    cnt: 5
  - name: vijaya
    cnt: 5
- static_configs:
  - location:
    datacenter:
```

I would expect to produce the required `my.yaml`, after update:

```yaml
---
- someotherkey: hello
  value: some_value
- someotherkey1: hello1
  value1: some_value1
- monitor_vms:
  - name:  sujana
    cnt: 5
  - name: vijaya
    cnt: 5
  - name: neo1
  - name: neo2
  - name: neo3
  - name: alice1
  - name: alice2
  - name: alice3
- static_configs:
  - location:
    datacenter:
```

Comment: :-) by mistake. By standard they are [3 dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Good catch @EdMorton

Answer (score 1):

You never need sed when you're using awk, you're letting shell variables expand to become part of scripts, and you have other shell errors in your code. As a starting point you should copy/paste all your scripts into http://shellcheck.net and fix the errors it tells you about.

This uses GNU awk for "inplace" editing since you were using GNU sed to do the same:

```
$ cat myscript.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"
shift
awk -i inplace -v vms="$*" '
/^-/ {
    if ( $2 == "monitor_vms:" ) {
        inBlock = 1
    }
    else {
        prtVms()
    }
}
$1 == "-" {
    prev = $0
}
{ print }
END { prtVms() }

function prtVms(    vmsArr, i, n) {
    if ( inBlock ) {
        sub(/:.*/,":",prev)
        n = split(vms,vmsArr)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            print prev, vmsArr[i]
        }
    }
    inBlock = 0
}
' "$file"
```

```
$ cat my.yaml
---
- someotherkey: hello
  value: some_value
- someotherkey1: hello1
  value1: some_value1
- monitor_vms:
    - name:  sujana
      cnt: 5
    - name: vijaya
      cnt: 5
- static_configs:
   -  location:
      datacenter:
```

```
$ ./myscript.sh my.yaml neo1 neo2 neo3 alice1 alice2 alice3
```

```
$ cat my.yaml
---
- someotherkey: hello
  value: some_value
- someotherkey1: hello1
  value1: some_value1
- monitor_vms:
    - name:  sujana
      cnt: 5
    - name: vijaya
      cnt: 5
    - name: neo1
    - name: neo2
    - name: neo3
    - name: alice1
    - name: alice2
    - name: alice3
- static_configs:
   -  location:
      datacenter:
```

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton. When I tried to run I was getting the error like this.Not sure what I am doing wrong.........??                                                                                         Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options: (standard)
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
        -v var=val              --assign=var=val
Short options:          GNU long options: ...........

Comment: I'm guessing you're running a very old version of gawk. What does `awk --version` output? If it's not `GNU Awk 5.1.0` or newer then install a new version of gawk as yours is out of date. If you can't do that for some reason then just get rid of the `-i inplace` option and do `tmp=$(mktemp) && awk 'script' file > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" file` like you would with any tool to overwrite the original input file with the tool output. That'll work with any awk and it's what sed, awk, perl, ruby, python, etc.. do in the background when called with an option to do so-called "inplace" editing anyway.