# bash script to edit yaml usimg awk

Tags: bash, awk, yaml

I am new to bash.. looking some advise on one issue mentioned below.
I have config file below.

### impulse.yaml

```
- job_name: orch
  value: CPST
- group: indalco
  value1: wr
- monitor:
    - name: quid
      cnt: 2
    - name: kwid
      cnt: 3
    - name: knid
      cnt: 4
- interval: 3m
- static_configs:
   - targets: targets1
      labels:
          group: BSA
          gid: geo
          dc: lba
```

if i run the bash script, it should update like below

### need to be updated impulse.yaml

```
- job_name: orch
  value: CPST
- group: indalco
  value1: wr
- monitor:
    - name: quid
      cnt: 2
    - name: kwid
      cnt: 3
    - name: knid
      cnt: 4
    - name: orch_vm1
    - name: orch_vm2
- interval: 3m
- static_configs:
   - targets: targets1
      labels:
          group: BSA
          gid: geo
          dc: lba
```

------------------bash script---------

```
getline() {
 awk '
 BEGIN { ln=1; find_monitor=0; }
 (find_monitor==1 && $0~/^[a-z]/) { exit }
 ($0~/^monitor:/) { find_monitor = 1 ;ln = NR }
 END { print ln }' ${1}
}

word="monitor" # no use of this variable
echo $line
filename="impulse.yaml"

for vm_name in orch_vm1 orch_vm2; 
  do
   line=`getline $filename $word`
   sed -i -e ${line}"a\    - name: \"${vm_name}\" " $filename
```

the code right now is updating at the begning of the monitor section of yaml file like below..but it needs to be updated at the end of the monitor section before interval section. Please advise what pattern matching technic can be applied.

```
- job_name: orch
      value: CPST
    - group: indalco
      value1: wr
    - monitor:
        - name: orch_vm1
        - name: orch_vm2
        - name: quid
          cnt: 2
        - name: kwid
          cnt: 3
        - name: knid
          cnt: 4
    - interval: 3m
    - static_configs:
       - targets: targets1
          labels:
              group: BSA
              gid: geo
              dc: lba
```

Comment: Don't post using 2 different accounts (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts for how to fix that) and learn from answers to your previous questions (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69270185/1745001), don't start from nothing again as you have here.

Comment: Hang on. This is exactly the same question as [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69270185/1745001). Don't keep posting the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @LéaGris’ comment. Structured data like YAML should be interpreted via its defined syntax. Traditional command line tools can't do this. [yq](https://dev.to/vikcodes/yq-a-command-line-tool-that-will-help-you-handle-your-yaml-resources-better-8j9) is the closest analogue